# To change the select to textBox when a particular item is selected?

Tags: angular

I have been trying to achieve the UI, if particular option is selected in select tag in Angular it should change to textBox

This is my select code

```
 <td><select [(ngModel)]="data.name" (change)="onSearchChange(i)">
      <option *ngFor="let k of changeVariable" value="{{k.key}}">{{k.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

How can I do that,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe it more in detail?

Comment: Upon clicking a particular value in drop down, the select should be replaced by  ```<input [(ngModel)]="data.name" (input)="onSearchChange(i)" />```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf` here something like

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="data.name" (change)="onSearchChange(i)" *ngIf="data.name !='yourValue'">
          <option *ngFor="let k of changeVariable" value="{{k.key}}">{{k.name}}</option>
        </select>

    <input [(ngModel)]="data.name" (input)="onSearchChange(i)" *ngIf="data.name =='yourValue'"/>
```

**Update**
       Use some flag like `isInputVisible`

```
   <select [(ngModel)]="data.name" (change)="onSearchChange(i)" *ngIf="!isInputVisible">
          <option *ngFor="let k of changeVariable" value="{{k.key}}">{{k.name}}</option>
        </select>

    <input [(ngModel)]="data.name" (input)="onSearchChange(i)" *ngIf="isInputVisible"/>
```

and in your `onSearchChange`

```
isInputVisible:boolean
onSearchChange(value){
if(value =='yourValue')
this.isInputVisible=true;
}
```

Comment: wait let me try

Comment: It sure have done, but it changes as soon as i try to edit, thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `*ngIf` to replace a particular element based on the value state like:

```
<input *ngIf="data.name" [(ngModel)]="data.name" (input)="onSearchChange(i)" />
<select *ngIf="!data.name" [(ngModel)]="data.name" (change)="onSearchChange(i)">
      <option *ngFor="let k of changeVariable" value="{{k.key}}">{{k.name}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes thats what m trying, actully is a dynamic form, where we can add form, so i need to maintain a array with true and false. Btw thanks for answer

Comment: Yes that's what we didn't know. You need to put in more information to get a proper answer.